# attractive part of Lennard-Jones potential derivation

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

The question is taken from this site:

http://www.chem.konan-u.ac.jp/PCSI/web_material/LJ.pdf

I don't see how they can end up with this element:

$\frac{3x^2}{2r^2}$                    (I)

my attempt: In the Taylor series used they have the third element $\frac{3x^2}{8}$ but they use $x=\frac{-2zz_1+x^2_1+y^2_1+z^2_1}{r^2}$ and I can't justify (I)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at $ \left (\dfrac{-2zz_1+r^2_1}{r^2} \right )^2$ = with $r^2_1 = x^2_1 + y^2_1 +z^2_1$.

You get
$$\dfrac{4z^2z^2_1}{r^4}-\dfrac{4zz_1r_1^2}{r^4}+\dfrac{r^4_1}{r^4} = \dfrac{4z^2_1}{r^2}-\dfrac{4z_1r^2_1}{r^3}+\dfrac{r^4_1}{r^4}$$

with the first term being the only significant one.